# User Details form after click on submit in survey form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have developed a Quiz from where Each question has to load in separate page with options (click-type), certain questions will have more than one answer with Others option as well. At the end of the questionnaire, the user must fill-up the form.

I have created survey from but I am not able to get user details form after survey form when user click on final question's answer.

I have attached my code please me

```js
(function() {
    var questions = [{
        question: "Does Your Business have IT Security Policies and Procedures?",
        choices:[ "yes",
"No"],
    }, {
        question: "What is 8*9?",
        choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
        correctAnswer: 0
    }, {
        question: "What is 1*7?",
        choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        correctAnswer: 3
    }, {
        question: "What is 8*8?",
        choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
        correctAnswer: 4
    }];

    var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
    var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
    var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

    // Display initial question
    displayNext();

    // Click handler for the 'next' button
    $('#next').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Suspend click listener during fade animation
        if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        choose();

        // If no user selection, progress is stopped
        if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
            alert('Please make a selection!');
        } else {
            questionCounter++;
            displayNext();
        }
    });

    // Click handler for the 'prev' button
    $('#prev').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        choose();
        questionCounter--;
        displayNext();
    });

    // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
    $('#start').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        questionCounter = 0;
        selections = [];
        displayNext();
        $('#start').hide();
    });

    // Animates buttons on hover
    $('.button').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $('.button').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
    // the answer selections
    function createQuestionElement(index) {
        var qElement = $('<div>', {
            id: 'question'
        });

        var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
        qElement.append(header);

        var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
        qElement.append(question);

        var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
        qElement.append(radioButtons);

        return qElement;
    }

    // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
    function createRadios(index) {
        var radioList = $('<ul>');
        var item;
        var input = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
            item = $('<li>');
            input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
            input += questions[index].choices[i];
            item.append(input);
            radioList.append(item);
        }
        return radioList;
    }

    // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
    function choose() {
        selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
    }

    // Displays next requested element
    function displayNext() {
        quiz.fadeOut(function() {
            $('#question').remove();

            if (questionCounter < questions.length) {
                var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
                quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
                if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
                    $('input[value=' + selections[questionCounter] + ']').prop('checked', true);
                }

                // Controls display of 'prev' button
                if (questionCounter === 1) {
                    $('#prev').show();
                } else if (questionCounter === 0) {

                    $('#prev').hide();
                    $('#next').show();
                }
            } else {
                var scoreElem = displayScore();
                quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
                $('#next').hide();
                $('#prev').hide();
                $('#start').show();
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

```css
    CSS INDEX
    ===================
 
    1. Theme Default CSS (body, link color, section etc)
    2. Header Area
    3. Slider Area
    4. Feature Area
    5. Service Area
    6. Video Area
    7. Features Carousel Area
    8. Pricing Area
    9. Clients Area
    10. Blog Area
    11. Download Area
    12. Contact Area
    13. Footer Area
    14. Image, Solid, Gradient, Transparent, Video Background Area
    15. Light Section Style
    16. Layout Two Style
    17. Scroll Up Start
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*----------------------------------------*/
/*  1. Theme default CSS
/*----------------------------------------*/
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html, body {height: 100%;}
.floatleft {float:left !important;}
.floatright {float:right !important;}
.floatnone {float:none !important;}
.alignleft {text-align:left !important;}
.alignright {text-align:right !important;}
.aligncenter {text-align:center !important;}
.no-display { display:none; }
.no-margin { margin:0 !important; }
.no-padding { padding:0 !important; }
a:focus, button:focus {outline:0px solid}
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border:0; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
.fix {overflow:hidden}
p {
    font-family: "Neuton",serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
a {transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active, a:hover, a:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none
}
ul{
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.clear{clear:both}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.browserupgrade {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}
::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}
body {
  color: #D0D0D0;
  font-family: "montserratregular";
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
#header {
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
#logo{
 clear:both;
 margin:20px;
}
#logo a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -18px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <!-- Basic Page Needs -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
    <title>Security Simplified</title>
 
 <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.css" >

    <!-- Theme Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
 
</head>
<body class="no-transition stretched">

<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
<header id="header" class="full-header">

     <!-- Logo-->
     <div id="logo">
      <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=" Logo"></a>
     </div><!-- #logo end -->
</header>   

<div id='quiz'></div>
            <div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></div>
            <div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Prev</a></div>
            <!-- <button class='' id='next'>Next</a></button>
                <button class='' id='prev'>Prev</a></button>
                <button class='' id='start'> Start Over</a></button> -->
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
```

Comment: what i got that you want to display the result of the quiz after he finish like 3/5 , in other word you need the implementation of displayScore function, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I get the error

```
displayScore is not defined
```

And I also can't find the part the part in your JS, where you have defined this function. 
Or are you aware of this is missing and are you searching for the code of this function? In this case it would be helpful to know exactly what the function should do with which variables.